# How does a person become a Rathi, Atirathi or Maharathi?

Tags: mahabharata, war

I want to know when and how a person acquires the Maharathi, the Atirathi or any other warrior title. Please provide a scriptural reference to support your answer.

Comment: Check [this site](https://www.historybaba.com/2019/03/mahabharat-warrior-ranking.html). It’s in Hindi and doesn’t have a scriptural backing they’ve given a definition right from a soldier of the infantry to a Maharathi.